# Using with structure - Non-matching count results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem in one of my MSSQL2008 works as told below. My query is:

```
;with WaitingCounts 
AS 
( 
  SELECT mt.id, COUNT(*) as cts
  FROM #myTable mt
  where mt.StatusId != 1
  group by mt.id 
)
UPDATE #myTable 
SET mt.TotalWaitingRecords=WaitingCounts.cts 
FROM #myTable mt
INNER JOIN WaitingCounts ON mt.id = WaitingCounts.id
```

My problem is, when I run the Select part only (the one inside AS(..) ), I see the result:

```
id   cts
10   438
```

Then I am removing the records whose statusId = 1 via:

```
delete from #myTable where StatusId = 1
```

After that, when I run the entire code, then run the query `Select id, TotalWaitingRecords from #myTable where id=10 group by id, TotalWaitingRecords`, I see that:

```
id  TotalWaitingRecords
10       802
```

I could not find out the reason why it is happening, 802 should be 438!. I appreciate if someone gives me a clue. Thanks.

Comment: Without some table definitions and sample data to reproduce this issue nobody can do much but speculate.

Comment: One thing that I will speculate on though, is that you're keeping duplicate, calculated data in your database (storing the total counts, which you can always just calculate), which is almost certain to give you many headaches in the future.

Comment: On running the query, records with `StatusId != 1` will be updated. This will cause them to different value when you query the records in table again. So where is the confusion?

Comment: try the `SET` clause without the `mt.` alias

Comment: @Tom ty for the advise;)

Comment: @pradeep edited question.

Comment: @sean I might put table definition but I cant put sample data does it work for u?

Comment: @devio it didnt work out.

Comment: I've attempted to reproduce and was unable. Without a minimal set of data that demonstrates the issue, there isn't anything else that I can do at this point.

Comment: `Then I am removing the records whose statusId != 1 via: delete from #myTable where StatusId = 1`... that query should be `delete from #myTable where StatusId != 1`